# SMTP Pickup directory not working

Tags: asp.net, smtpclient

I'm trying to save my email in a local directory.
This is my code present in the web.config

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
        <network host="localhost" />
        <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="c:\Temp\mail\"/>
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

I don't get errors but the mail is not present in the directory specified. It is possible that the mail ends up in a (spam)filter?

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm experiencing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the fact that you have both a `<network>` and a `<specifiedPickupDirectory>` element in there is the problem.  Remove the `<network>`.

Here's a working example:
web.config

```
 <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="HelloWorld@yourdomain.com" deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
        <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="c:\dcs\smtp" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

Code behind (VB):

```
   Protected Sub startMailing(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim msg As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
        Dim smtpSrvr As New SmtpClient
        msg.To.Add("wylie@acme.com")
        msg.Subject = "Fish Goes paddling Down the stream."
        msg.Body = "Row Row Row Row"
        smtpSrvr.Send(msg)
    End Sub
```

Comment: when i remove it, I get error like the smtp host was not found.